# How to dynamically display items in the screen navigated after list selection in Powerapps?

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-formula, powerapps-selected-items

Below shows the image of the items in the vertical gallery in Powerapp:

[image]

Below is the image of the screen for checklists content:
[image]

This is the sample data:
[image]

Desire outcome: For instance, if I select "office" item in the vertical gallery, it  should navigate me to a screen showing the checklists for the office.
Let's say if I go back and select "Meeting room" item in the vertical gallery, it should navigate me to the SAME screen showing the checklists for the meeting room.
In short, I want to on list item select to navigate me to the same screen and change the content (checklists) of the screen dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the selected row of the gallery with `Gallery.Selected` from the checklists screen. This will give you access to the selected row/record in the data source that is feeding the Gallery control on the first screen.

Comment: Any examples :( @SpencerL

Comment: For example, a screen could have a gallery named `Gallery1` whose `Items` property is bound to `Table({ Field: 1 }, { Field: 2 })`. Another screen could contain a label control whose `Text` property is set to `Gallery1.Selected.Field`. If `Gallery1` or one of its children controls had a `Navigate` call for `OnSelect` that navigated to the screen with the label, the label would show the `Field` value from the selected row of the gallery.

Comment: I dunno where all these canvas-app functions are supposed to put like for instance to put in OnChange or OnSelect? :O @SpencerL

Comment: Could you post a sample of the above based on my values provided? @SpencerL

Comment: In your case, you would want to update the `OnSelect` of the gallery itself or the `OnSelect` of the right arrow control inside the gallery. I would recommend putting it on the gallery, so that you can click anywhere in the row of the gallery to trigger the `OnSelect`. However, in this case you will want to ensure that the controls inside the gallery have `Select(Parent)` so that when they are clicked, the `OnSelect` of the gallery is run.